# How can we get the partial derivate of a function that has two variables in a parenthesis at power k?

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

Basically the title.
I remembered a professor showed this once in class but i don't really remember it. So I'm not even sure if there is any.
But basically, is there a way of getting $\frac{\partial}{\partial a} (a - x)^2$ without opening the parenthesis?

Comment: Just use chain rule:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial a}(a-x)^k = k(a-x)^{k-1}\cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial a}(a-x) = k(a-x)^{k-1}$$

Comment: thanks, that's how i was doing it in my head, but it never actually clicked that that was like a general relation.